# Run in root shell from within a user bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I have a script that , among other things, needs to do some stuff as root, like creating a mount folder.
I tried:

```
echo "Linux user password is needed in order to ..."
sudo -s
# also tried:
# sudo su
... code that requires root permission
exit
... code that requires user permission
```

The problem is that the script stops after the "sudo -s" and continues only after I manually exit the automatically created root shell.

**Is there a way to run root shell commands within a user script?**

Thanks.

Comment: Creating a mount folder does not require root-priviledges. If a user has write permissions to a folder he can create directories there. There is propably a better way without sudo or stuff like that.

Comment: I agree with @Nils, but also... why don't you create a second script with all the functionality that needs root privileges? Then just call it with `sudo` from the first script.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since things like

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mymountpoint
```

work, you can do

```
sudo ./myrootscript.sh
```

and if you check for suitable parameters, your script could even call itself again, so you'd just have one file.

Comment: and if you needed to do it as a specific user, you can pass a `-u $username` to sudo.  like `sudo -u oracle lsnrctl start` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply using both `sudo` and `su` in a wrong way. If you write just `sudo -s` or `sudo su` alone, you will end up with an interactive shell created from inside the script - *this is what those comands **do***.

Since you need *a chunk of shell code* to be executed as root, you need to wrap it somehow into a single command. Probably the simplest way is to use an explicit subshell:

```
echo "Linux user password is needed in order to ..."
sudo sh -c '
 ... code that requires root permission
'
```

That, of course will cause trouble when you try to use some variables defined elsewhere in your script - in such case, use double quotes instead of single.

**But** if you only have several commands to be run as root, better use `sudo` in front of each of them.